# Two power sources, one 3-way switch?

Tags: electrical

I am attempting to build a charging station for all of our electronics. I would like to set it up so for each device there is a light switch and an outlet for its power adapter.

If it is switched one way, it is straight power like it's plugged into the wall. If it is switched the other way, it will go into a timing circuit where it will only get power for 2 hours a day (to maintain charge when not in use).

I would I have a 'timed hot' (T.H.) and an 'always hot' (A.H.) supply line entering the circuit but I    am not sure where to go from here as far as the rest of the wiring.

Is this possible and if so, how? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you trying to power a single duplex receptacle, two single receptacles, or separate halves of a duplex receptacle?

Comment: This question should probably be closed as off topic, since it's a hobby project and not DIY **Home Improvement**.

Comment: I was thinking it was permanent wiring near a counter or something ... that would be a kind of a nice feature in the kitchen or near an entry door.  \

Comment: @Tester101 this might be on topic at Electronics.SE.  I'm not sure though; it might be worth pinging one of their mods before throwing it over the wall since it's probably going to be closed here.

Comment: We don't have a real reason to close, but it should be as it's asking for non-code compliant solutions.  It would be on topic for Electronics, if the permanent wiring restriction were removed.

Answer (score 9):

I personally think you are going way overboard with what you propose. These days all your newer stuff charges with 5V on USB Type A connectors. The charge controllers inside your phone / tablet / GPS / whatever else are smart and will service the internal battery in the proper way. So there should be no need for this two hours per day timed behavior.

So if you have five devices to charge [get one of these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VH8ZW02). For ten devices get two.

[image]

Comment: Lithium ion or lithium polymer batteries don't have a memory and will do just fine waiting on the charger until you want to use them. A switched power supply like the ones in these chargers only use power when there is a load on them. And today's electronics only take power when they need it to maintain the battery. Unlike the old style transformer wall warts that consumed power all the time.

Answer (score 7):

You can wire this as follows with a timer and some 3-way switches:

[image]

- The incoming hot feeds all switches on one traveler terminal, and the timer.
- The switched output on the timer feeds the other traveler terminal on each switch.
- The common screw on the 3-way feeds the hot on an outlet. (Red wire in diagram.)
- Neutrals and grounds all around, as required.

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't realize there was a DIY section for this. This would be plugged in like a giant power bar. Thank you so much for this schematic and answer. This is exactly what I was looking for! :) 
I can't go the big USB hub route because it's not just USB devices I am dealing with - laptops, 3DSs, GPS units and running watches all need mains power unfortunately. I figured this would be an easy way to make sure everything remains charged without having them plugged in all the time. One adapter is minor, but 20 devices sure adds up!

Again, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Awesome diagram!  There's also [3-way switch/receptical](http://www.menards.com/main/general-purpose-electrical-switches/combination-3-way-switch-and-tamper-resistant-outlet/p-1444427450481.htm) combo devices that could clean up this install quite a bit.

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn red lines.  Would be +2 if you worked hand-drawn red circles into it.